# ElasticSearch Date Math find out what it's calculating

Tags: elasticsearch

So I would like to know what `now-1y` is producing as a result. So is it:

1. `now - 365days`
2. `now - 365.25days`
3. now with the year part subtracted, so `2014-12-23T08:46:00`

I've read this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) but can't find any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some testing it appears that the third proposition is correct (ie "now with the year part subtracted, so 2014-12-23T08:46:00"

If 2 was correct the following example should have return 2 results.
[example1](https://www.found.no/play/gist/828b4ccb3b8dc9c8a51c)

As 2012 is a leap year. The following example should return 0 result if 1 was correct.
[example2](https://www.found.no/play/gist/faf92ffe7da4d8e08549)

Note: example only worked as expected when I wrote this answer, in order to make it work for you, you have to update the date field of the indexed document.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the general question asked above: use the validate API.

indexname/_validate/query?rewrite=true

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "modifiedDate": {
        "gte": "now-1y/y",
        "lte": "now/y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And you get:

```
{
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "valid": true,
  "explanations": [
    {
      "index": "indexname",
      "valid": true,
      "explanation": "+modifiedDate:[1640995200000 TO 1704067199999] #FieldExistsQuery [field=_primary_term]"
    }
  ]
}
```

This lets you see exactly what value is being used for a given query.